# How to find the relevant variables/features in a confusionmatrix?

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I have a dataframe(df) with a binomial output. I split my df in training and testdata in R. I used randomforest and my confusionmatrix gave me the following output:

Reference (horizontal)

prediction (vertical)

___  0 _ 1

0 _ 34 _  3

1 _ 800 _ 10000

I won't analyse the accuracy and those '800' doesn't bother me either, but i want to find out which features are relevant to predict the value 0. I could use the code: importance(fitRF, type =2)

But i want to know the specific relevant features voor class 0. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the `lime` package.

Comment: Is it not possible to change my code into something like this?  
                                                                                        
 importance(fitRF, class=0, type =2). Is it only possible with Lime?

Comment: No. Black box models are not so easy. You can also look into the package `DALEX`. More info [here](https://pbiecek.github.io/DALEX_docs/). Both `lime` and `DALEX` will only explain what variables led to the outcome. You will have to figure out the rest.